# How to select elements on a given point in AutoCAD?

Tags: .net, vba, autocad

I'm currently porting some AutoCAD VBA code to .NET and came across the following part:

```
Dim oSSetObj As AcadSelectionSet = Nothing
oSSetObj = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add(SelSet_Prev)
oSSetObj.SelectAtPoint(pInsertionPoint)
```

So, I have a given point and I want to select all elements at this point. I took a look at different methods of the `SelectionSet` and the `Editor` class, but none of them seem to fit to my requirement.

How can I select all elements in AutoCAD .NET at a given point? The solution should work in AutoCAD 2008 and 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you have to iterate over the whole database: http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2006/11/two_methods_for.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I took a look at Kean's blog, but I missed that article. And the first option seems to work for me.